# Java 8 : ZonedDateTime will not support enum Month, but it will accept DataTime object which contains enum Month

Tags: enums, java-8, zoneddatetime

I'm working on `ZonedDateTime` while passing arguments to the `ZonedDateTime.of(1990,Month.JANUARY,20,10,20,30,400,zoneId);` , it will not take `Month.JANUARY` as the argument, but when I'm passing the `DateTime` object with the `enum Month.JANUARY`, it will works fine. Why `ZonedDateTime.of()` method will not support `enum Month.JANUARY`.

In the future, are they going to add the method which will support `ZonedDateTime.of` method with `enum Month.JANUARY`

**Example:**

```
package com.katte.infa;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class DateTimeDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.of(1990, 1, 1,12,20,20);
    System.out.println("DateTime1:" +dateTime1);

    LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.of(1990, Month.JANUARY, 1,12,20,20); // enum Month.JANUARY
    System.out.println("DateTime2:" +dateTime2);

    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();

    ZonedDateTime zdateTime1 = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime1,zoneId);
    ZonedDateTime zdateTime2 = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime2,zoneId); // enum Month.JANUARY, works fine

    System.out.println("ZdateTime1 :" +zdateTime1);
    System.out.println("ZdateTime2 :" +zdateTime2);

    ZonedDateTime zdateTime3 = ZonedDateTime.of(1990,10,20,10,20,30,400,zoneId);
    ZonedDateTime zdateTime4 = ZonedDateTime.of(1990,Month.JANUARY,20,10,20,30,400,zoneId); // not compile 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `LocalDateTime.of()` is as follows:

```
public static LocalDateTime of(int year, Month month, int dayOfMonth,
                               int hour, int minute, int second)
```

While that of `ZonedDateTime.of()` is:

```
public static ZonedDateTime of(
        int year, int month, int dayOfMonth,
        int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoOfSecond, ZoneId zone)
```

As you can see, `ZonedDateTime.of()` 's 2nd arg `int month` accepts an `int`, you can not pass a `Month` instance in it.

But `LocalDateTime.of()`'s 2nd arg `Month month` accepts a `Month`.

If you want to use `Month` in `ZonedDateTime.of()`, you can use it via `Month.JANUARY.getValue()`. The `getValue()` function returns an `int` in the range `1-12`, which is a valid range for month arg of `ZonedDateTime.of()`. The following example works fine:

```
ZonedDateTime.of(1990, Month.JANUARY.getValue(),20,10,20,30,400,null);
```